# How can I find the longest string within a list? Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, max

Using only prelude functions, how can I return the longest string in a list of strings?

e.g

```
["abc","ab","cb"]
```

will return

```
"abc"
```

Comment: You could probably do it with a fold and a lambda.

Comment: The answer to that question uses imported modules. I am trying to only use prelude

Comment: @Arthur uh, seriously, is `Data.List` import a problem?

Comment: @Arthur See the second answer then.

Comment: @Snps Your right, I will flag it

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to limit yourself to only using Prelude functions, here's one straightforward solution:

```
longest :: [String] -> String
longest xss = snd $ maximum $ [(length xs, xs) | xs <- xss]
```

That is, you first pair each element of the list with its length, then take the greatest pair according to a lexicographic ordering, and then finally drop the length component of this pair, leaving you with the longest string.

---

As others have also pointed out, allowing yourself to use other libraries as well, makes it considerably easier to write this function. For example, importing `maximumBy` and `comparing` from, respectively, `Data.Ord` and `Data.List`, enables you to write your function simply as

```
longest = maximumBy (comparing length)
```

Trading `comparing` for `on` from `Data.List`, you can write it as

```
longest = maximumBy (compare `on` length)
```

These last two versions have as an advantage that they have a more general type, i.e., `[[a]] -> [a]`, then the all-Prelude function that I gave above, which can have its type generalised to `Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]` at best.

Answer (score 1):

```
> import Data.List
> import Data.Ord
> maximumBy (comparing length) ["abc","ab","cb"]
"abc"
```

Comment: he only wants prelude

Answer (score 0):

A simple `fold` should do:

```
λ> foldl1' (\acc x -> if length acc > length x then acc else x) ["aaa","c","ffff"]
"ffff"
```

In each iteration, it's comparing whether `acc` is larger than the current element of the iteration and returns the largest element. But note that `foldl1'` will crash when you give empty input list.

Comment: Something like `foldl (\x y -> if x > y then x else y) "" []` would solve the empty list problem.

Comment: @matsjoyce Yeah, I wanted to leave that as an exercise to the OP :P

Comment: as somone new to haskell, can you explain the 1' at the end of foldl. Also, how is acc assigned? I am trying to implement this in a script

Comment: @Arthur `foldl1'` is a variant of `foldl` function. You can look at the definition of`fold` to get a better understanding. This [chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) explains foldl nicely.